# Show that if A is an m x n matrix and B=U*AV, then A*A and B*B have the same trace.

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

**Show that if $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $B=U^*AV$, where $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices of sizes $m \times m$ and $n \times n$ respectively, then $A^*A$ and $B^*B$ have the same trace.**

Really what I want to know is if this part is acceptable, but I included the whole question above for context:

> If I have $\text{tr}(V^* A^* A V)$, by rules of trace products, $\text{tr}(V^* A^* A V) = \text{tr}(V^* V A^* A )$.
>
> and $V^* V =I$ (  by def. of unitary)
>
> then $\text{tr}(V^* A^* A V) = \text{tr}(A^* A)$.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$B=U^*AV \to B^*B=(V^*A^*U)(U^*AV)=V^*A^*AV$$

So

$$tr (B^*B)=tr(V^*A^*AV)=tr(A^*AVV^*)=tr(A^*A)$$

Ps.: I'm using that $tr(XY)=tr(YX)$ and then $tr(V^*(A^*AV))=tr((A^*AV)V^*)$.

Comment: What you're saying is what I'm saying - yes?  I don't see a difference, and I want to make sure I fully understand the concepts

Comment: @Snackbreak: you are right! I didn't check your question properly!

Comment: @Snackbreak: your solution is the same. It is right!

Comment: you are very welcome!